# Javascript Code for Jquery Read/Change function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been using the following with no trouble, where when I revise 'b_down' above 20, the span id 'pmi' is removed from the page. However, it is dependent on a jquery.min.js file (shown). The problem is I have another jquery.js that allows numerous other javascript based features to run on the site, but within that file the code that makes the change event work apparently is not there. When I reference the googleapis jquery.min.js file, the change feature I want works, but then other features are disabled.

I have spent several hours trying to figure out exactly what bit of code in that 
googleapis jquery.min.js file makes the change event fire, so I can isolate it to get my change event added to the site w/o disabling the other features connected to the jquery.js file.

I have pretty much looked everywhere for the 'companion' .js code that the script apparently needs but have found nothing. The script is common, but every example I have found always adds the googleapis jquery.min.js script reference (or something similar) as without it, the script wont work.

So, I was wondering what is the javascript predicate to:

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function (){
            $("#b_down").change(function() {

                if ($(this).val() < 20 ) {
                    $("#pmi").show();
                }else{
                    $("#pmi").hide();
                } 
            });
        });
  </script>
```

Instead of blindly going at it like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function (){
            $("#b_down").change(function() {
                // foo is the id of the other select box 
                if ($(this).val() < 20 ) {
                    $("#pmi").show();
                }else{
                    $("#pmi").hide();
                } 
            });
        });
    </script>
```

because

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

conflicts with another .js file I reference in my header,

```
 <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Please provide the **.js** was conflicted.

Comment: For starters, you should avoid using two versions of jQuery in your page.  Why are you doing that?  If you were going to do that, then there's an involved procedure for allowing two separate versions of jQuery to co-exist at the same time (though your first order of business should be to avoid using two versions).

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not a javascript expert, and the many features on the site work very well with the jquery.js file, where when replaced with the googleapis js file they don't, but a feature I like wont work w/o both files. I am all for condensing them. If I could isolate exactly what is in that googleapis js file that makes that little bit of code fire, I would delete the rest, and I doubt there would be any conflict with the other file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an elegant and simple solution for this 'show/hide' issue that did not involve any third party .js reference files. Below is working code, where 'el' can be anything you want, as well as 'order', for example you could use 'function zebra(zoo)' as long as on the other side of 'var x' you have 'zoo.value', and inside the select tag, your onchange event matches the function name, i.e 'onchange="zebra(this)"'.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function order(el) {
var x = el.value;

if (x >= 20) {
document.getElementById('pmi').style.display = 'none';
} else if (x < 20) {
document.getElementById('pmi').style.display = 'block';
} 

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select name="b_down" id="b_down" onchange="order(this)">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
</select>
<p>
<span id="pmi">
Span Content
</span>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

what version is your JQuery.js file?

All the methods your referencing should be in there, there may just be subtle differences in implementation.

```
$(function(){ .. });  -- is equivalent to $(document).ready(function() { .. });

$("#id").change(fn)  -- is equivalent to $("#id").on("change", fn)
```

after binding the change event verify that the dom element was found

```
$(function (){
  $("#b_down").change(function() {
     var value = parseInt(this.value);
     alert("inside change event: " + value);
     $("#pmi").toggle(value < 20);
  }); 

  if ($("#b_down").length == 0)
     alert("#b_down dom element is not found");  
  });
});
```

Comment: Version: jQuery v2.1.3 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license

Comment: Your script should work without the jquery.min.js.   I would use fiddler or browser tools network tab to determine if a 3rd jQuery library is being downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid conflicts you can call `ready` directly from `jQuery` object and it will pass the `jQuery` instance to the `ready` callback as a parameter:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){
   $("#b_down").change(function() {

      if ($(this).val() < 20 ) {
         $("#pmi").show();
      }else{
         $("#pmi").hide();
      } 
   });
});
```

So you can use `$` inside the ready callback without any problem.

Comment: fwiw, I tried that, exactly as shown,`<html>
 <head>
 <script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function ($){
    $("#b_down").change(function() {
       if ($(this).val() < 20 ) {
          $("#pmi").show();
       }else{
          $("#pmi").hide();
       } 
    });
 });
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 
 <select id="b_down" name="b_down"> 
 <option value="">Select</option> 
 <option value="1">1</option><option value="2" >2</option><option value="30" >30</option>
 </select>
 
 <span id="pmi"> 
 Test
 </span>
 </body>
 </html>`  and without that googleapis file referenced, nothing

Comment: You must include jquery library !